# react native why there is a time lag in setState function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a checkbox that calling two functions on on press event , in the first function I am changing the state of the component , on the second function I am calling that state to see if it has been changed by the first function,
by displaying the state of that component by console.log I see that changes are displayed only after second click on the checkbox , so first click empty data displayed , seconde click data and changes are displayed on the console , would you please help me understand why there is that time lag ?

this is my code :

```
<CheckBox  onPress={() => {this.treggerCheckBoxcallback(item); this.editeTask()}} />

//function 1
  treggerCheckBoxcallback = tsk => {
    let currentTasks = tsk;
  this.setState({ currentTask : currentTasks});
      };

// function 2
   editeTask = () => {
    console.log(this.state.currentTask);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950287/react-native-setstate-not-updating-immediately-when-logging-in-console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function `setState` is asynchronous, so your console log shows the state right before the setState is really called. To avoid such behavior you can use setState like this:

```
this.setState({ data: yourData }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.data)
  // code called after the setState is finished. (callback)
})
```